# Event Hub - not getting expected throughput

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, azure-eventhub

I have setup an instance of Event Hub with 20 Throughput units and 32 partitions on Standard Tier. As per documentation, every throughput unit equates to 1 MB/second. So ideally I should be getting throughput of 20 MB/second or 1.2 GB/minute. The namespace has only one event hub and I am the only user. The event hub is set up in West US which is the option closest to where requests are sent from.

However, I see that it takes at least 10 minutes to 1.77GB of data. I am using async batch calls and packing each request to the 1 MB limit. I see a vast variance in time taken by SendBatchAsync call - it varies from 0.15 to 25 seconds.

Here is my code :
(Please note : I am constrained to use .Net Framework 4.5)

```
    static EventHubClient eventHubClient;        

    static Dictionary<int, List<EventData>> events = new Dictionary<int, List<EventData>>();
    static Dictionary<int, long> batchSizes = new Dictionary<int, long>();

    static long threshold = (long)(1e6 - 1000);

    static SemaphoreSlim concurrencySemaphore;
    static int maxConcurrency = 1;
    static void Main()
    {
        eventHubClient = EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, eventHubName);

        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();            

        using (concurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency))
        {
            foreach (string record in GetRecords())
            {
                Tuple<int, EventData> currentEventDetails = GetEventData(record);
                int partitionId = currentEventDetails.Item1;
                EventData currentEvent = currentEventDetails.Item2;

                BatchOrSendAsync(partitionId, currentEvent);

            }

            SendRemainingAsync();
        }

        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("### total time taken = {0}", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString()));

    }

    static async void BatchOrSendAsync(int partitionId, EventData currentEvent)
    {
        long batchSize = 0;

        batchSizes.TryGetValue(partitionId, out batchSize);
        long currentEventSize = currentEvent.SerializedSizeInBytes;

        if( batchSize + currentEventSize > threshold)
        {
            List<EventData> eventsToSend = events[partitionId];
            if (eventsToSend == null || eventsToSend.Count == 0)
            {
                if (currentEventSize > threshold)
                    throw new Exception("found event with size above threshold");
                return;
            }

            concurrencySemaphore.Wait();
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            await eventHubClient.SendBatchAsync(eventsToSend);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString());
            concurrencySemaphore.Release();

            events[partitionId] = new List<EventData> { currentEvent };
            batchSizes[partitionId] = currentEventSize;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!events.ContainsKey(partitionId))
            { 
                events[partitionId] = new List<EventData>();
                batchSizes[partitionId] = 0;
            }
            events[partitionId].Add(currentEvent);
            batchSizes[partitionId] += currentEventSize;
        }
    }

    static async void SendRemainingAsync()
    {
        foreach(int partitionId in events.Keys)
        {                
            concurrencySemaphore.Wait();
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();                
            await eventHubClient.SendBatchAsync(events[partitionId]);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString());
            concurrencySemaphore.Release();
        }
    }
```

Note : increasing the maxConcurrency for the semaphore only degrades the overall time taken and the SendBatchAsync call starts erroring out when maxConcurrency is 10

What should I do to improve throughput?

Comment: Is your data evenly distributed over the partitions? I see you set the partitionId manually.

Comment: Good point...I will check that...regardless, it takes at least 0.15 seconds to send a batch of 1 MB whereas I'm paying for a throughput of 20 MB/s...Ideally 1 MB data should be sent in 0.05 seconds ....by the way, I should have also added this - 1) the time taken per call has a trend to it...it starts in the range of 0.15 seconds and keeps increasing until 0.6 seconds and then drops back to 0.15s range...this pattern keeps repeating....and it between I see ome calls taking 11s, 15s, 25s every now n then... and 2) if I remove the partitionKey, it still takes about the same 0.15s per call on avg